# Table hiding via checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to hide the table i have when the checkbox is unticked. I'm doing it wrong because its not working!

Whats missing?

this is my table class

```
<table class="table table-bordered invoiced">
```

This is my javascript

```
  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).toggle();
});
```

and this is my checkbox class

```
<th><input name="invoiced" type="checkbox" checked> Invoiced Out</th>
```

Comment: Your input has no `name` attribute?

Comment: tried that didnt work but yes my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox hasn't got name attribute so I have changed it to get class also you have space between your table and class in click function, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e2bhuL4/1/)

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){        
  var column = "table." + $(this).attr("class");
  $(column).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Still not working, Not sure why it should be working because its working in the js fiddle. Wondering if its something to do with the rails inside also and its conflicting?

Comment: Check browser's dev console (F12) see if there are any errors

Comment: Nothing coming up inside the console

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is make sure these click events are inside document.ready or load